# UrlFetchApp before and after javascript

Tags: google-apps-script, urlfetch

I have an apps script that grabs a URL and returns it's contents. I want to then search the page for a specific string, before the javascript worked on the page. Then, I want to evaluate that same page after javascript has done it's thing.

The reason is that I have a 3rd-party script that replaces phone numbers on the page, based on region. I want to evaluate the original, before javascript source, to see if one of the replaceable numbers exists. If it does, I want check the after-javascript version to verify if it's been replaced with a number from that region.

I can do this manually by choosing "View Source" in the browser, then checking the Inspect Element where that string was found.

My problem is that I can't get the original source from UrlFetchApp.  Is there a way to do that?

Thanks in advance,
Hans

--

Code

```
var doc = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
// doc is the after-javascript version...
```

Comment: `UrlFetchApp.fetch()` returns the contents retrieved from the HTTP request. No Javascript code retrieved from the call is executed. You can use local applications for making requests (such as curl, postman or insomnia http) to verify this behaviour - all should return the same response (without JS execution). Could you perhaps provide the URL you are trying to fetch, and the data you are attempting to extract from it? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I see what happened. I was searching body.innerText.  However, CSS was hiding the <div> (visibility: invisible) with the phone number I was searching for, and apparently innerText doesn't return divs like that. I though the phone number was being swapped out to the regional one already.  Thanks!

Comment: Hey @Hans as far as I know, even if the div is set to invisible you should still be able to obtain the data from it. Would you mind creating an answer explaining your findings? Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

I just ran a test on an example website and found that UrlFetchApp does return the original source before JS rendering. I believe `.fetch()` works like a standard HTTP GET request, so I don't see why this wouldn't be the case.

**Example:** https://tutorialzine.com/2015/02/single-page-app-without-a-framework

UrlFetchApp Result Snippet:

```
<ul class="products-list">
    <script id="products-template" type="x-handlebars-template">
        {{#each this}}
            <li data-index="{{id}}">
                <a href="#" class="product-photo"><img src="{{image.small}}" height="130" alt="{{name}}"/></a>
                <h2><a href="#"> {{name}} </a></h2>
                <ul class="product-description">
                    <li><span>Manufacturer: </span>{{specs.manufacturer}}</li>
                    <li><span>Storage: </span>{{specs.storage}} GB</li>
                    <li><span>OS: </span>{{specs.os}}</li>
                    <li><span>Camera: </span>{{specs.camera}} Mpx</li>
                </ul>
                <button>Buy Now!</button>
                <p class="product-price">{{price}}$</p>
                <div class="highlight"></div>
            </li>
        {{/each}}
    </script>
</ul>
```

Post-JS Render Result:

```
<ul class="products-list">
    <script id="products-template" type="x-handlebars-template">
        ​
                {{#each this}}
                    <li data-index="{{id}}">
                        <a href="#" class="product-photo"><img src="{{image.small}}" height="130" alt="{{name}}"/></a>
                        <h2><a href="#"> {{name}} </a></h2>
                        <ul class="product-description">
                            <li><span>Manufacturer: </span>{{specs.manufacturer}}</li>
                            <li><span>Storage: </span>{{specs.storage}} GB</li>
                            <li><span>OS: </span>{{specs.os}}</li>
                            <li><span>Camera: </span>{{specs.camera}} Mpx</li>
                        </ul>
                        <button>Buy Now!</button>
                        <p class="product-price">{{price}}$</p>
                        <div class="highlight"></div>
                    </li>
                {{/each}}
    </script>
    ​
    <li data-index="1" class="">
        <a href="#" class="product-photo"
            ><img
                src="assets/images/sony-xperia-z3.jpg"
                height="130"
                alt="Sony Xperia Z3"
        /></a>
        <h2><a href="#"> Sony Xperia Z3 </a></h2>
        <ul class="product-description">
            <li><span>Manufacturer: </span>Sony</li>
            <li><span>Storage: </span>16 GB</li>
            <li><span>OS: </span>Android</li>
            <li><span>Camera: </span>15 Mpx</li>
        </ul>
        <button>Buy Now!</button>
        <p class="product-price">899$</p>
        <div class="highlight"></div>
    </li>
    <li data-index="2" class="">
        <a href="#" class="product-photo"
            ><img src="assets/images/iphone6.jpg" height="130" alt="Iphone 6"
        /></a>
        <h2><a href="#"> Iphone 6 </a></h2>
        <ul class="product-description">
            <li><span>Manufacturer: </span>Apple</li>
            <li><span>Storage: </span>16 GB</li>
            <li><span>OS: </span>iOS</li>
            <li><span>Camera: </span>8 Mpx</li>
        </ul>
        <button>Buy Now!</button>
        <p class="product-price">899$</p>
        <div class="highlight"></div>
    </li>
    <li data-index="3" class="">
        <a href="#" class="product-photo"
            ><img src="assets/images/htc-one.jpg" height="130" alt="HTC One M8"
        /></a>
        <h2><a href="#"> HTC One M8 </a></h2>
        <ul class="product-description">
            <li><span>Manufacturer: </span>HTC</li>
            <li><span>Storage: </span>32 GB</li>
            <li><span>OS: </span>Android</li>
            <li><span>Camera: </span>5 Mpx</li>
        </ul>
        <button>Buy Now!</button>
        <p class="product-price">899$</p>
        <div class="highlight"></div>
    </li>
    <li data-index="4" class="">
        <a href="#" class="product-photo"
            ><img
                src="assets/images/galaxy-alpha.jpg"
                height="130"
                alt="Galaxy Alpha"
        /></a>
        <h2><a href="#"> Galaxy Alpha </a></h2>
        <ul class="product-description">
            <li><span>Manufacturer: </span>Samsung</li>
            <li><span>Storage: </span>32 GB</li>
            <li><span>OS: </span>Android</li>
            <li><span>Camera: </span>12 Mpx</li>
        </ul>
        <button>Buy Now!</button>
        <p class="product-price">899$</p>
        <div class="highlight"></div>
    </li>
    <li data-index="5" class="">
        <a href="#" class="product-photo"
            ><img
                src="assets/images/nokia-lumia.jpg"
                height="130"
                alt="Nokia Lumia"
        /></a>
        <h2><a href="#"> Nokia Lumia </a></h2>
        <ul class="product-description">
            <li><span>Manufacturer: </span>Nokia</li>
            <li><span>Storage: </span>16 GB</li>
            <li><span>OS: </span>Windows</li>
            <li><span>Camera: </span>5 Mpx</li>
        </ul>
        <button>Buy Now!</button>
        <p class="product-price">450$</p>
        <div class="highlight"></div>
    </li>
    <li data-index="6" class="">
        <a href="#" class="product-photo"
            ><img src="assets/images/zte-nubia.jpg" height="130" alt="Zte Nubia"
        /></a>
        <h2><a href="#"> Zte Nubia </a></h2>
        <ul class="product-description">
            <li><span>Manufacturer: </span>ZTE</li>
            <li><span>Storage: </span>32 GB</li>
            <li><span>OS: </span>Android</li>
            <li><span>Camera: </span>12 Mpx</li>
        </ul>
        <button>Buy Now!</button>
        <p class="product-price">399$</p>
        <div class="highlight"></div>
    </li>
    <li data-index="7" class="">
        <a href="#" class="product-photo"
            ><img
                src="assets/images/galaxy-s5.jpg"
                height="130"
                alt="Samsung Galaxy S5"
        /></a>
        <h2><a href="#"> Samsung Galaxy S5 </a></h2>
        <ul class="product-description">
            <li><span>Manufacturer: </span>Samsung</li>
            <li><span>Storage: </span>16 GB</li>
            <li><span>OS: </span>Android</li>
            <li><span>Camera: </span>15 Mpx</li>
        </ul>
        <button>Buy Now!</button>
        <p class="product-price">399$</p>
        <div class="highlight"></div>
    </li>
    <li data-index="8" class="">
        <a href="#" class="product-photo"
            ><img src="assets/images/iphone5s.jpg" height="130" alt="Iphone 5S"
        /></a>
        <h2><a href="#"> Iphone 5S </a></h2>
        <ul class="product-description">
            <li><span>Manufacturer: </span>Apple</li>
            <li><span>Storage: </span>16 GB</li>
            <li><span>OS: </span>iOS</li>
            <li><span>Camera: </span>8 Mpx</li>
        </ul>
        <button>Buy Now!</button>
        <p class="product-price">399$</p>
        <div class="highlight"></div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. See comment above. body.innerText was not returning the text I was looking for because the div was hidden.